# How to make Bootstrap dropdown act like a real dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to set a default value to Bootstrap dropdown and also once a value i selected, the selected value displays. I'm not sure where to start but I have the fiddle included.

So I want the dropdown to say "Document #" by default, and once I select Party ID, then it stays there.

```
<input type=text placeholder='search text' />
<div class="btn-group">    
    <button class="btn btn-info">SEARCH BY</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Document #</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Party ID</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uPd3C/)

Comment: you'll need to use javascript, jquery or some framework like knockout/Angular etc. if you're o.k. with a scripting lang. let me know and I'll post a simple demo for you.

Comment: @origin1tech, how about jquery? and needs to support at least IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go Ray:

There are several ways to do this and I did this a little more verbose than I would personally but this was to help you understand what's happening..cheers.

Updated fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/chazelton/uPd3C/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// you'll need to change these option values to whatever you need them to be.
var options = ['PartyID', 'two', 'three'];
var ddl = $('ul.dropdown-menu');
ddl.append('<li class="active"><a href="#">Please Select</a></li>')
$.each(options, function (k,v) {
       var li = $('<li><a href="#">' +  v + '</a></li>');
     li.data('value', v);
    li.on('click', function () {
        var val = $(this).data('value');
        $('ul.dropdown-menu li').removeClass('active');            
         $('input.result').val(val);
        $('button.search').text('SEARCH BY ' + val);
        $(this).addClass('active');
     });
     ddl.append(li);              
 });
});
```

Comment: Not quiet what I want. First it's loaded, I want the SEARCH BY to say "SEARCH BY DOCUMENT #", and after I choose "PARTY ID", i want it to say "SEARCH BY PARTY ID".

Comment: give me a sec I'll change that.

Comment: I did something like this with your hint of jquery, but maybe there's a better way: http://jsfiddle.net/uPd3C/3/

Comment: you just need to change the "options" array there to whatever values you want them to be. Just follow along what I did there and you should be good to go. Please mark as answered thx.

Comment: I got the idea. I like the class=active part.

Comment: quick 101 on selectors. you can select a lot of ways. I like using classes as opposed to id="myid". So say I have a bunch of drop downs if I setup my jq selector as select.mydrops where mydrops is the class then all I have to do is add that class and whamo it works. For bootstrap the "active" is what they use to show it as selected state.